# How to configure NSPredicate with multi-constraints

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Now I have a filter class, such as:

```
@interface Filter:NSObject {
    NSString *a,
    NSString *b;

    BOOL aisset;
    BOOL bisset;
}
```

and I have a function to get objs from core data, such as:

```
(NSArray *)findObjs:(Filter *)filter;
```

How to implement this function? For this case, I know the answer:

```
...
if (!aisset && !bisset) {
}
else if (aisset && !bisset) {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a==%@", a];
}
else if (!aisset && bisset) {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"b==%@", b];
}
else if (aisset && bisset) {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a==%@ AND b==%@", a, b];
}
...
```

But how to deal with three variables, for example a, b, c?

I have try this way:

```
...
NSString *predicateStr = @"";
if (aisset) ...
if (bisset) ...
if (cisset) ...
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@", predicateStr];
...
```

but if I run with this code, I will get an error :'Unable to parse the format string "%@"'.

Comment: Why are you storing your `BOOL`s as pointers?

Comment: @Jenox my mistake, done!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", predicateStr,valueToCheck];`

If tou ant to combine those conditions, you could use `appendFormat`.

## UPDATE

You should use `NSCompoundPredicate`. It let's you combine those predicates

```
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

 if (aisset)
 [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a==%@", a]];
if (bisset)
 [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"b==%@", b]];
...
NSPredicate *finished = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpreds];//Your final predicate
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what's the value of "valueToCheck"

Comment: It is your a,b,or c,wether it meets on of isset conditions

Comment: NSString *first = @"a == %@";
first = [first stringByAppendingFormat:@"AND b == %@"];

Comment: I think this is same to what I write in problem. Finally, predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@", first]; if you run with this code, you will get an error 'Unable to parse the format string "%@"'